# Using GHCJS-DOM without webkitgtk

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghcjs, ghcjs-dom

I have installed GHCJS and compiled a few "Hello, World" programs.  Now I'd like to work with the DOM.  Does anyone know if it is possible to install the ghcjs-dom package without webkitgtk?  I'm having a lot of difficulty loading the webkitgtk package, and I really just want to work with the DOM at this point.

Comment: I've been using ghcjs with the ghcjs-dom package and never installed webkitgtk ( at least not intentionally and as far as I know not at all ).  How are you going about installing ghcjs/ghcjs-dom ?

Comment: @Dave I run `cabal install ghcjs-dom`, sometimes with different variants.  It keeps getting hung up on something like `Failed to install webkitgtk3-0.14.1.1`.  Is there a better way?

Comment: have you installed ghcjs already ?  I believe you should do this as a first step.

Comment: Yes, I have done that successfully

Comment: Here's a project I created to try out ghcjs :  https://github.com/dc25/ghcjs_demo

Comment: Cloned and tried to compile...when I ran `ghcjs -o demo Main.hs` I got 
`Main.hs:1:8: Could not find module ‘GHCJS.DOM’`` and other errors for all the DOM extensions.  How did you install the DOM package?

Comment: If you clone that project, you should be able to run the following commands...

    cabal configure --ghcjs;
    cabal sandbox init;
    cabal install --only-dependencies --ghcjs;
    cabal configure --ghcjs;
    cabal build;

... from within the project to build using ghcjs.  The extra configure command was necessary for me because the project seems to forget the ghcjs configuration after the install

I just verified that this works on my ubuntu linux machine.  The "cabal install" took about 10 minutes

You "cabal" will need to be up-to-date enough to support the --ghcjs option.

Comment: You must already have ghcjs-dom installed.  When I run `cabal configure --ghcjs` I get `cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing: ghcjs-dom`

Comment: Those cabal commands were supposed to be on different lines.  The comment system had other plans though so I added semicolons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100703/discussion-between-dave-and-mark-karavan).

Comment: The answer given is more succinct than the steps mentioned in the comments above and discussed in the chat.  If you just want to use the ghcjs-dom library with ghcjs, then all you need to do is "cabal install ghcjs-dom --ghcjs".  At that point, the ghcjs-dom functionality is available for import and you can compile with ghcjs ( "cabal build" is not required ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install ghcjs-dom for use with ghcjs use :

```
cabal install ghcjs-dom --ghcjs
```

This requires a version of cabal recent enough to include ghcjs support.